# Error on vb6 "Run-Time Error -2147319779 Automation error Object library not Registered"

Tags: vb6

Hi guys i am having trouble using the FileSystemObject in Windows7 Home Premium'm getting an error message "Run-Time Error -2147319779 Automation error Object library not Registered" I used this code on windows xp sp3 and it worked good, I tried Registrer dll "c: \ windows \ system32 \ scrrun.dll" but is still showing the error, Thank you all!

```
Set Diretorio = FSO.GetFolder(DiretorioDinamico)'The error occurs here!
```

Comment: The error occurs there? What's the code before that? Are you creating FSO "the usual way", or what is FSO? Could you show us how and where you define/initialize FSO? Also, what is DirectorioDinamico? Is it a string? What did you dim Directorio as an object, a Folder?

Comment: The diretoriodinamico is a string, this function returns a folder object for the diretorio only not working in Windows7 home premium, tested on Windows XP and Windows7 starter there are no errors, but when I was testing on Windows home premium showed this error, thanks

Comment: Is the workstation your are getting the error on running a 64-bit version of Win 7 Home Premium?

Comment: my version is of 32 bits

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue with bad registration of some common components installed on `syswow64`, among them the `mscomctl.ocx`. After searching for and not found a solution, I derived one that solved the problem. So, the only way to solve was:

1. Unregister the `mscomctl.ocx` (with elevated privilegies)
2. Disabled the Internet Explorer (version 10 in my case)
3. Reboot the system
4. Register the `mscomctl.ocx` (Always elevated)
5. Enabled IE10 again

It seems to be IE10 the problem. Since I disabled it, I could finally correctely register the common controls.

I hope (despite my bad english) help someone who is facing the same problem.

Comment: This is a long version of "how to do I reset the kill bit for my old and insecure version of mscomctl".  The remote execution security flaw is rated "critical", the bulletin [is here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms12-027).  Avoid doing this on machines that you don't own.